# How do acids conduct electricity with H+ ions?

Tags: acid-base, electrochemistry

I know that ions can conduct electricity, but H+ ions has no electrons! How can it conduct electricity then. Like if we were talking about Cl- or Na+ then these ions do have electrons.

But how can something that has no electrons be used to conduct electricity?

Also, do acids conduct electricity only in water and not on their own?

And, do acids also stop conducting electricity after all the ions have been deionized? (like NaCl aqueous solution)

Comment: Electrons are very much **not** a magic substance that is involved whenever someone talks about electricity. It is **electric charge** that matters, and $\ce{H+}$ surely does have one.

Comment: so how can a positive charge conduct electricity?

Comment: Just like a negative charge does: by moving around.

Comment: so we can do the same thing with a proton too? If yes, then what about bases? They have a OH- ions. How can it conduct electricity?

Comment: What same thing? All ions have electric charge. Therefore they conduct electricity whenever they move. That's the reason for conductivity of electrolytes.

Comment: so we use molecules as electrons? Do we only need something to move?

Comment: we use molecules instead of electrons to produce electricity and we make them move due to their charge. That is what I got

Comment: Again, electricity does **not** mean that electrons are involved.

Comment: ok thx for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acids by themselves don't necessarily conduct electricity.
An example is boron tribromide, a Lewis acid.
What makes acid (aqueous) solutions good conductors, is the capability of the acid of interacting with water molecules, by creating positive and negative charged ions.

Comment: how does that help in conducting electricity?

Comment: Because the transmission of electricity involves the movement of charged particles (be them ions, such as in ionic solutions, or electrons, such as in metals).

Comment: ok, thx for your answer